# React native flatlist leaves empty spaces, for items that don't match conditions

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

[image: Example picture]

The first row shows a single card, this is because the item suppose to be there doesn't match the condition stated. But I want to remove this space, and put the next card which is currently on the next line there.

```
{state.data ? <FlatList
                data={state.data}

                renderItem={({ item }) => {
                    console.log(item)
                    return (
                        <View style={{ justifyContent: 'space-evenly', marginHorizontal: 0 }}>
                           <View>

                                {item.available == 1 ?
                                    <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={.8} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Appointment', { id: item.id, name: item.name, phone: item.phone, email: item.email, session: item.session, player_id: item.player_id, picture: item.picture })} >
                                        <Card style={{ width: width / 2.05, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', borderRadius: 15, paddingTop: 10, height: height / 2.4 }}>
                                            <CardItem cardBody>
                                                <Image
                                                    source={{ uri: 'http://example.com/storage/' + item.picture }}
                                                    style={{ height: 200, width: null, flex: 1 }}
                                                />
                                            </CardItem>
                                            <CardItem>
                                                <Text> {item.name} </Text>
                                            </CardItem>
                                        </Card>
                                    </TouchableOpacity>
                                    :   null}


                            </View> 

                        </View>

                    )
                }}
                numColumns={2}

            /> : <ActivityIndicator size="large" style={{ alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }} />}
```

The null value just shows that empty space, is there a way to completely remove this empty space?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to filter your data. Otherwise, your code will create empty Views.

Try to filter your data as follows.
It would be good if you move this filter logic from your render method.

```
{state.data ? <FlatList
        data={state.data.filter(item => item && item.available === 1)}

        renderItem={({ item }) => {                
            return (
                <View style={{ justifyContent: 'space-evenly', marginHorizontal: 0 }}>
                   <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={.8} 
                   onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Appointment', { id: item.id, name: item.name, phone: item.phone, email: item.email, session: item.session, player_id: item.player_id, picture: item.picture })} >
                        <Card style={{ width: width / 2.05, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', borderRadius: 15, paddingTop: 10, height: height / 2.4 }}>
                            <CardItem cardBody>
                                <Image
                                    source={{ uri: 'http://example.com/storage/' + item.picture }}
                                    style={{ height: 200, width: null, flex: 1 }}
                                />
                            </CardItem>
                            <CardItem>
                                <Text> {item.name} </Text>
                            </CardItem>
                        </Card>
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                </View>

            )
        }}
        numColumns={2}
    /> : <ActivityIndicator size="large" style={{ alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }} />}
```

Comment: It didn't work that way, cos state.data doesn't exist data has been fetched. So I'm getting undefined evaluating state.data

Comment: @SimiloluwaOdeyemi I don't how you set your data but I'm going to edit one more time. Hope that this time it would help.